How to properly show decrypted text in bound label of FormView
I am using CryptoJS to encrypt a sensitive field and write the encrypted value to the database. This works well. But now I want to decrypt the value and display the value to a bound label within a FormView called "FvActions", using the javascript CryptoJS.AES.decrypt method.
The Show_Decrypt function takes three parameters. Parameter 1 is the control name to get the cyphered text from and will have the decrypted value written to., Paramter 2 is the cyphered text, and parameter 3 is the cypher key to be used by CryptoJS to decrypt. Here is the javascript that's in  tags:
        function Show_Decrypt(tx, str, key) {
        var t = "#" + tx;
        var s = str.toString();
        var ky = key.toString();
      
        var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(s.toString(), ky.toString());
        $(t).innerHTML = decrypted;
    }

Now this is the Formview Code
Private Sub fvactions_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles fvactions.ItemDataBound

    Dim lbl As Label = e.Item.FindControl("ptLabel")
        Dim epcrlbl As Label = e.Item.FindControl("Lblepcr")
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "keyLicDtlz", "Show_Decrypt('" & lbl.ClientID.ToString & "','" & lbl.Text.Trim & "','" & epcrlbl.Text.Trim & "');", True)


End Sub

I can see in the console that the parameters are being passed to the function however, following error is shown.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
The error seems to be generated at the '+' sign in the passed in parameter #2.
Show_Decrypt('ContentPlaceHolder1_fvactions_ptLabel_0','U2FsdGVkX1+6tq8s40Z63HaZMOmvUpeYioFwZMFG9Ps=','CF777');Show_Decrypt(ContentPlaceHolder1_fvactions_ptLabel_0,U2FsdGVkX1+6tq8s40Z63HaZMOmvUpeYioFwZMFG9Ps=,CF777);
I hope I've provided enough info. Please help.

Figured it out!
I had to use the string.replace() function to replace the special characters that were causing the unexpected token problem and then replace the special characters back when calling the decrypt function.
